# Need help on compiling DPDK hello world

Tags: dpdk

I try to learn DPDK using the following link: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/build_app.html

I have downloaded DPDK 19.11.1 version in Ubuntu 16 virtual machine. Then unzipped the tar.gz file. Then I have given the following commands

```
~/DPDK$ cd examples/helloworld/  
~/DPDK/examples/helloworld$ export RTE_SDK=/home/vijay/dpdk  
~/DPDK/examples/helloworld$ export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc  
~/DPDK/examples/helloworld$ make
```

The following error is displayed:

> /home/vijay/dpdk/mk/internal/rte.extvars.mk:29 cannot find .config in /home/vijay/dpdk/build. stop

If I put sudo make, the following error is displayed

```
Makefile:44: *** "Please define RTE_SDK environment variable". stop
```

When I put echo $RTE_SDK and echo $RTE_TARGET the values are printed correctly.  I tried x86_64-native-linux-gcc for RTE_TARGET also.

I tried multiple times and referred to different sources. Not sure whether I miss any steps in the process. What can I try next?

Comment: have you build your target 'make config T=$RTE_TARGET O=$RTE_TARGET'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error logs, it looks like you have not built dpdk libraries in the desired target folder. To do it correctly

```
cd dpdk-main-folder
export RTE_SDK=$PWD
export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
make config T=$RTE_TARGET O=$RTE_TARGET
cd $RTE_TARGET
make -j 10
```

With these done go to your desired example and execute `make`

Comment: Thanks. I did the steps as you have mentioned. It's works fine.

Comment: I have faced the same proble “*** Cannot find .config in dpdk-20.05  Stop.” However I configure and make with meson and ninja. My steps: 1.cd dpdk-20.05 2.meson build --prefix=/my/target/path 3. cd build 4.ninja 5. ninja install. How should I do to solve the problem"*** Cannot find .config in dpdk-20.05  Stop."

Comment: already udpated the answer to the question, review accept and upvote to close the new question