# When I install IX(https://github.com/ix-project/ix), I ran into problems

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

When I run *make -sj64*, the following errors occur:

```
In file included from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_ether.h:50:0,   
                 from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_ethdev.h:185,  
                 from drivers/i40e.c:35:  
../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_memcpy.h:870:2: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of    ‘_mm_storeu_si128’
  MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47(dst, src, n, srcofs);        
  ^    
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/xmmintrin.h:1246:0,       
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/x86intrin.h:34,    
                 from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_vect.h:67,    
                 from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_memcpy.h:46,    
                 from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_ether.h:50,     
                 from ../deps/dpdk/build/include/rte_ethdev.h:185,     
                 from drivers/i40e.c:35:     
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/emmintrin.h:700:1: note: expected ‘__m128i’ but argument is of type ‘int’       
 _mm_storeu_si128 (__m128i *__P, __m128i __B)      
 ^    
make[1]: *** [core/dpdk.o] Error 1    
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....        
make[1]: *** [drivers/common.o] Error 1    
make[1]: *** [drivers/ixgbe.o] Error 1     
make[1]: *** [drivers/i40e.o] Error 1    
make: *** [dp] Error 2
```

I use VMware Workstation 15 Player and Ubuntu 14.04.

dubuntu@ubuntu:~/ix$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0xde
cpu MHz     : 2712.002
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec arat flush_l1d arch_capabilities
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf
bogomips    : 5424.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

Comment: I recommend first to check if standalone DPDK build for DPDK works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513785/need-help-on-compiling-dpdk-hello-world/62525938#62525938. This can be done `deps/dpdk`. you have sse4_1 and sse4_2 which is minimum requirement. Please update with the result

Comment: @Telsa can you share you update?

Comment: I have checked the makefile and arguments passed for building the project and found that `-I../deps/dpdk/build/include -I../deps/dpdk/lib/librte_eal/common -I../deps/dpdk/drivers/net/ixgbe -I../deps/dpdk/drivers/net/i40e`. These are not enough to built with DPDK libraries. IF using DPDK  < 19.11, use `make -d or make v=1` to identify the DPDK flags. A quick fix will be add `-mavx -msse4.2` as CFLAGS too.