# *** Cannot find .config in /home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/build

Tags: dpdk, ninja, meson-build

Similar questions to [Need help on compiling DPDK hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513785/need-help-on-compiling-dpdk-hello-world). However my DPDK version is v20.05, I have to use meson and ninja to build my DPDK,so the solution doesn't work for me.

I built my DPDK following the link:https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html.

Before building my DPDK, I pre-set:

```
export RTE_SDK=/home/cxx/dpdk-20.05
export RTE_TARGET=build
```

My building commands:

```
meson build --prefix=/home/cxx/dpdk-20.05
cd build
ninja
ninja install (I don't run the"ldconfig" command)

cd /home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/examples/helloworld 
make
```

the error shows:

```
/home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/mk/internal/rte.extvars.mk:29: *** Cannot find .config in /home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/build.  Stop.
```

So, I run the command below to see if the .config file really doesn't exist.

```
cd /home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/build 
find . -name ".config"
```

The result shows that there is actually no ".config" file in /home/cxx/dpdk-20.05/build.

Why did I lose the .config file and how can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Try to format code pieces such as `export RTE_SDK=/home/cxx/dpdk-20.05...` with backticks `(this symbol: \` )`. One starting backtick and one ending backtick.

Comment: Thanks for your suggetion. I have re-formated my code pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT-1] the real issue is

1. mix up the steps between makefile build and meson-ninja.
2. Since you have used prefix the default PKG_CONFIG is not able to point to `libdpdk.pkg`

Explanation: From DPDK version > 19.11 LTS onwards support for `meson ninja` is fully integrated with the removal of Makefile. Hence one needs to use `meson ninja` only. So the right steps to follow are

1. Do not execute the steps

```
export RTE_SDK=/home/cxx/dpdk-20.05
export RTE_TARGET=build
```

2. If the intention is to `built DPDK and install in default path`, then execute

```
untar dpdk.tar
cd dpdk-folder
meson [desired folder name]
cd [desired folder name]
ninja
ninja install
ldconfig
```

3. But if the intention is to `built and save the libraries and header files in different folder` then

```
untar dpdk.tar
cd dpdk-folder
meson [desired folder name] --prefix=[folder to hold the built dpdk libraries and headers]
cd [desired folder name]
ninja
ninja install
ls [folder to hold the built dpdk libraries and headers]
```

In order to build helloworld with step-2, `gcc helloworld.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libdpdk)` is sufficient.
But in order to make use of libraries and headers from the custom folder, `one requires to point PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the custom folder which has libdpdk.pkg`. This will allow the libdpdk.pkg to be used from the custom folder, not `/usr/lib/`.

steps to follow

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=[dpdk master folder]/[custom folder path where libdpdk.pkg is located]
gcc helloworld.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libdpdk)
```